# Y-axis labels on spiderweb graphs

Tags: highcharts

There seems to be a bug with the rendering of labels on the y-axis of spiderwebgraphs when using 'gridLineInterpolation:'polygon', the labels are positioned correctly when not using it and they seem to keep the same position. See https://www.evernote.com/shard/s44/sh/f04023fb-d6ed-4b59-baad-f2181bd4de64/5d9f780d6f5511bbe7cf53a4eb94d595

Relevant configuration:

```
yAxis:{
  gridLineInterpolation:'polygon',
  lineWidth:0,
  min:0,
  max:5,
  tickInterval: 1,
  labels: {
      enabled: true, x: 0, y: 0, step: 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same bug with Highcharts 4.1.3 but it's fixed in version 4.1.9

Thus, the simplest thing to do is to update Highcharts version.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this option is not supported, but you can request your suggestion here: highcharts.uservoice.com